# vueJs updating props even though i am method variable

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-props

I have the following method compares two array, one coming from the props and the other one from my own component. Every element that exists in my props array but doesnt exist in my components array is inserted in a third array with the added property called "destroy : true" so i can send it to the back end to be deleted from the database.

However for whatever reason my props is being updated instead of the variables i use in the method to do all this. i am not really sure why since i am not referencing the prop directly but i do copy its content to the variables in the method.

```
     updateArray(){
        let updatedArray = []
        let oldArray = [...this.props.array]
        oldArray.forEach(element => {
          if(this.componentArray.indexOf(element) > -1){
            updatedArray.push(element)
          }else{
            let newElement = element
            newElement.destroy = true
            updatedArray.push(newElement)
          }
        })
       return updatedArray 
},
```

why does this happen exactly? every other element in my component works fine except this.

Comment: `my props is being updated instead of the variables i use in the method` ...how exactly? Pls describe **exactly** what you expect and what you see instead....

Comment: i expected only the 'element' inside the forEach loop to be update with the new object property but it ends up updating the props instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Comment: so from what i understand if it is a simple value i make a copy of it but if it is a more complex value, like arrays and objects i am making instead a reference to it which is why this is happening

Comment: That is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are copying the **elements** of the `this.props.array` array into a new array local to the method but given that the elements of the array are objects, both arrays are in the end containing **same** objects ([references to the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value))

You can create *shallow copy* of the original element with the spread operator `let newElement = { ...element }` - this creates the completely new object and copy all properties of the original object. But be aware that if any property of original objects contains array/object, you have the same problem... just one level down